# How to change textSize of menu item in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, menuitem

I have simple navigation menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".view.SaleActivity">

   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sum"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

I'd like to change the items text size. I've been looking for some time and
adding `android:textSize="20sp"` doesn't work and nor does `app:itemTextAppearance="@style/CustomMenuItemText"`.

This is my style for the `CustomMenuItemText`:

```
    <style name="CustomMenuItemText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
    </style>
```

Am I doing something wrong with the style or I have to change the textSize different way?
I want to do it in xml.

Comment: You've got the right idea with that `<style>`, but you can't apply it in the `menu` XML. Instead, you would set it as the `actionMenuTextAppearance` in the `Activity`'s theme: `<item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/CustomMenuItemText</item>`. Also, you probably don't want to use a `DeviceDefault` style for the `parent`; rather, `parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu"`.

Comment: It seems to have worked but only for some items even tough they are the same, only thing that's different is title and id. weird. Thanks tho, You've set me on the right path.

Comment: I've found out what was wrong, the style is for actions so if it's false it doesn't apply to it, missed that bit. I'll find out how to give it style and everything should work so if you put it as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Yeah, that'll only affect the items in the `ActionBar` itself. I guess I assumed that's what you meant, given the `app:showAsAction="always"` on the example. If you want to style the overflow menu, too, I _think_ that'll be `actionBarPopupTheme`, but I'd have to do some digging for the details, as I don't remember them off-hand.